# C# DefaultControllerFactory that supports multiple repositories

Tags: c#

I have a rather simple implementation of the `DefaultControllerFactory` that allows one repository to be injected into a controller.

I'm looking to expand the solution to allow N number of repositories.

What I'm trying to achieve is to inject different repository for each controller I have.

**MyControllerFactory.cs**

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>> controllers;

    public MyControllerFactory(IRepository repository)
    {
        controllers = new Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>>();
        // I want this injected repository to be of type RepA
        controllers["Home"] = controller => new HomeController(repository);
        // I want this injected repository to be of type RepB
        controllers["About"] = controller => new HomeController(repository);
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return this.controllers.ContainsKey(controllerName) ? this.controllers[controllerName](requestContext) : null;
    }
}
```

I also have a helper class that is used for registration.

Here's the problem. This class only handles one repository, or am I seeing it wrong?

**ControllerFactoryHelper.cs**

```
public static IControllerFactory GetControllerFactory()
{
    string repositoryTypeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["repository"];
    var repositoryType = Type.GetType(repositoryTypeName);
    var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
    IControllerFactory factory = new MyControllerFactory(repository as IRepository);
    return factory;
}
```

And in the `web.config` I have the following key:

```
<add key="repository" value="RepTest.Repository.RepositoryA" />
```

And this snippet in the `Global.asax` file

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(ControllerFactoryHelper.GetControllerFactory());
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a dependency injection framework like Ninject or Unity? They would allow you in inject any number of dependencies in any combination.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking of that as well...using Ninject.

Comment: @user1620220 This is very true, but you still need to be able to decide which repo to inject into which controller (off topic, I found a horrendous bug in Ninject last week which can deadlock and hang IIS, so I'm personally staying clear of it for now)

Comment: @Rhumborl You typically declare your dependencies within the class that needs them (either as parameters to a constructor or as properties). So in each controller you would declare which repository(ies) it uses.